# UITabViewController is empty

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, xib, nib

I have a loginViewController as root. After login I want to set UITabBarViewController as rootViewController. I'm initing it with nib. But it empty when it appearson screen. all tabs I set in xib file are not shown.

Where is the problem, how do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the tab bar controller as you rootViewController, and then present modally your login view controller.

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
```